# Info about dataset from which a Huffman tree was generated

Tags: binary-trees, huffman-coding

I know that given the following huffman tree:

[image: A huffman tree]

you can say that C occurs most in the dataset from which it was generated and D and B occur the least. Can you also say that the left most leaf on a level has a occurence that is greater than or equal to the rightmost?

Comment: What are your thoughts?  Have you tried generating a counterexample?  Have you tried working through some examples?  Have you tried to prove your claim?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My claim was not true. I've found [counterexample](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HuffmanCoding.html) on mathworld. If you look on the 4th level, you will see that 5th element is not in the correct position (if my statement were to be true).